# Video Stitching using Open CV

Tags: python, opencv, video, opencv-stitching

I see questions and answers on image stitching using Open CV. Is it possible to stitch video using Open CV. Specifically using Python? I have Pycharm installed with Open CV and am able to get it to play one recorded file. But would be great to get it to read two and stitch them together. Would be grateful if anyone can point me to any tutorials that I haven't been able to find yet.
Thanks

Comment: `video` is treated as many images/frame so you may use CV with `for`-loop and `input_stream.read()` to get frame by frame, stitch frames to new frame and `output_stream.write()`  to write this frame to new file. But sometimes it may be simpler to use specialized modules like `MoviePy`, `ffmpeg-python`, `Manim`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `OpenCV` with `for/while` loop to read frame by frame from two videos, stitch frames in new frame (using `numpy` - ie. `hstack()`) and save it in new file (also frame by frame)

Later I create example.

---

But it may be simpler to use specialized modules like [MoviePy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy), [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) or [Manim](https://manim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
Probably all of them use program [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) which has many functions and filters.

---

Example with `MoviePy` - it creates array with with two movies in one row but it can create array with many rows and columns.

```
from moviepy.editor import *

clip1 = VideoFileClip('input1.mp4')
clip2 = VideoFileClip('input2.mp4')
              
final_clip = clips_array([[clip1,clip2]])  # two videos in one row 

final_clip.write_videofile('output.mp4')
```

And two videos in one column

```
final_clip = clips_array([[clip1], [clip2]])  # two videos in one column
```

And array 2x2 videos

```
final_clip = clips_array([[clip1, clip2], [clip3,clip4]])
```

---

**EDIT:**

Code with `CV`.

It is longer and more complex but it displays video.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

clip1 = cv2.VideoCapture('input1.mp4')
clip2 = cv2.VideoCapture('input2.mp4')

width  = clip1.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
height = clip1.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
fps    = clip1.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) 
print('fps:', fps)              

video_format = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP42')  # .avi 
final_clip   = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', video_format, fps, (int(width), int(height)))

delay = int(1000/fps)
print('delay:', delay)              

while True:

    ret1, frame1 = clip1.read()
    ret2, frame2 = clip1.read()    

    if not ret1 or not ret2:
        break
        
    final_frame = np.vstack([frame1, frame2])  # two videos in one row
    final_clip.write(final_frame)

    cv2.imshow('Video', final_frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(delay) & 0xFF
    
    if key == 27:
        break
    
cv2.destroyWindow('Video')

clip1.release()
clip2.release()
```